# How to save faces detected by cv zone

Tags: cvzone

I have code that detects a face. All I want to do is save the detected face as a jpg

Here is the code f

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

from cvzone.FaceDetectionModule import FaceDetector
from cvzone.FaceMeshModule import FaceMeshDetector

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
detector = FaceDetector()
meshdetector = FaceMeshDetector(maxFaces=3)
while(True):
    rec, frame = cap.read()
    frame, bbox = detector.findFaces(frame)
    print(bbox)
    print(type(bbox))
    print("------------------------")
    frame, faces = meshdetector.findFaceMesh(frame)
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)  
    keyexit = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if keyexit == 27:
        break

cv.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

How do I save the detected face? Please help!